# Geometry Nodes: How to scale and rotate instances based on segment length

Tags: geometry-nodes

1. Can you explain to me how to scale the instances (1,2,3) based on the 2-axis distance (segment length) up to the next curve point, based on the instance source point?
2. Can you explain to me how to rotate the instances to the next point position. The y-axis is the one I need to rotate.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Additional infos: The array models (fence parts) should be the same size like a curve segment. And if possible the elements should end dynamically at the nex point position of the curve.
With curve segment I mean the range between two curve points.

Comment: so do i understand you right, you want to make a fence? that fence should "start" at z = 0 for every part and height of the curve point?  and on each point there should be a fence part? or between two points?

Comment: The pink borders in my 1st shot describes how the results should look like. The fence height shouldn't change. Just the length should be scaled up to the next point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align the objects you want to instantiate at the points of a curve exactly to the curve segments, you can use the following setup:

[image]

Here I first simply calculate the direction vector between two points. This is the direction between the current point to be instantiated and the next point.

If you then remove the values for the *Z-axis*, you get the direction vector you are looking for.

This serves you as a vector to create a rotation with the node `Align Euler to Vector`.

The scaling is also achieved via this vector.

Simply determine the length and scale your objects with this value.

For example, if you use an object with length $1$, you can directly apply the length of the vector as scaling.

---

If the use of a *Bezier curve* is not suitable for your application, you can use a *Poly spline* instead. Of course you can also create this directly in Geometry Nodes by using the node `Set Spline Type`:

[image]

And here you can see the whole thing in action:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: ok, that was easy ;) i thought the OP wanted the fences to reach from curve point to curve point - so different length of each segment

Comment: ok, so your answer is not perfect ;) +1 -> read his newest comment :D

Comment: @Chris Ah, OK, indeed, there is something wrong. I started writing with the answer before the addition. That's what happens... ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I hope your solution still helps me to find the final solution. My main focus is to learn it myself. But I'm just an artist with basic technical knowledge and there are limits ... ;)

Comment: I thinks he wants different length for each curve segment. As I understood him, one fence segment should be from one curve point to the next curve point.

Comment: @Chris Different lengths are possible here. Just edit the curve according to your wishes and the fences will be adjusted in length. Have you tried it?

Comment: i don't like to disagree...but i still thinks he wants the fence from one curve point to his next curve point. So the resample node "destroys" here his plans ;) or you would use set position to "correct" the positions afterwards...but i cannot see that in your node tree...and yes, i tried ;) too many fence segments and not just between the curve points of the original curve

Comment: @Chris Then you just use a *Poly Line* instead, and leave out the Node `Resample Curve`, right?

Comment: yep, THAT'S the solution !!!! nice -> maybe change again the answer ;)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Thank you all for the hints, especially @quellenform . I'll post my documented solution later. I learned a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the final solution, how I need it. Thank you a lot again to everybody.
I've learned a lot!

[image]

The final file:
[image]